# Removing punctuation and change to lowercase in python CSV file

Tags: python, csv, lowercase

The code below allow me to open the CSV file and change all the texts to lowercase. However, i have difficulties trying to also remove the punctuation in the CSV file. How can i do that? Do i use string.punctuation?

```
file = open('names.csv','r')
lines = [line.lower() for line in file]

with open('names.csv','w') as out
     out.writelines(sorted(lines))

print (lines)
```

> sample of my few lines from the file:
>
> Justine_123
>
> ANDY*@3
>
> ADRIAN
>
> hEnNy!

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem?

Comment: i would like to also remove the punctuation in the CSV file. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with regular expressions.

```
import csv
import re

filename = ('names.csv')

def reg_test(name):

    reg_result = ''

    with open(name, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            row = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(row))
            reg_result += row + ','

    return reg_result


print(reg_test(filename).lower())
```

justine123,andy3,adrian,henny,

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by importing strings and make use of the following example code below.

> The other way you can achieve this is by using regex.

```
  import string
  str(lines).translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

Also you may want to learn more about [how import string works and its features](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

The working example you requested for.

```
  import string
  with open("sample.csv") as csvfile:
  lines = [line.lower() for line in csvfile]
  print(lines)
```

> will give you ['justine_123\n', 'andy*@3\n', 'adrian\n', 'henny!']

```
  punc_table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
  new_res = str(lines).translate(punc_table)
  print(new_res)
```

> new_s the result will give you justine123n andy3n adriann henny

Comment: i still can't remove the punctuation using the code you given.

Comment: Can you please post your text file sample so I can provide you a working example, instead of the above direct one

Comment: I'm sorry. im new to stackoverflow. is it possible to guide me through on how to post text file?

Comment: @JanelleKohHuiJuan, please can you use the same method of how you posted the question and paste just few line of your text file

Comment: is it also possible for me to change the csv file to string to split it ?